# Could not connect VM on port 22 in Google cloud

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, console, google-compute-engine

I have installed hadoop (HDP ) in the google cloud vm instance , after sometime when i tried to connect the machine again, it is showing error :
"We are unable to connect to  VM on port 22" .

Comment: use command "netstat -ntup" and see if the port 22 is assigned to some other process or not. As it seems to me that the port is assigned to some other process. If it is so, then kill that process and then try again.

Comment: I am not able to login in machine

Comment: Use port 2222. You may be able to login

Answer (score 0):

To get additional debug logs try to SSH using verbose flag using the following [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh):

```
$ gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE_NAME --zone ZONE --ssh-flag="-vvv"
```

If the above step doesn’t help, [connect](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole) to the instance using the serial console of the affected instance and check if this issue has to do with open port as Abhinav mentioned.

You find additional SSH troubleshooting information in the [Help Center Article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh).